# How to use jquery to remove extra whitespace before content in <textarea> without changing html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to use jquery append() to add content to a textbox without having to consider newline characters that show up in the html markup and indent the content. How do I get jquery to ignore newline characters in regards to textarea?

```
<div id = "content-frame">
<div id = "remove-frame">
<div id = "content">
    here is the content, click this content
  </div>
</div>
</div>


$("#remove-frame").click(function () {
var divContents = $("#content").text();
$("#content").remove();
$("#remove-frame").append(function() {
  return '<textarea id = "edit-textarea">' + divContents + "</textarea>";
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8KA8q/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed to [trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) the content value. Also you can use [JQuery.trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) to keep browser compatibility. Try to modify your code as bellow:

```
$("#remove-frame").click(function () {
  var divContents = $("#content").text().trim();
  $("#content").remove();
  $("#remove-frame").append(function() {
      return '<textarea id = "edit-textarea">' + divContents + "</textarea>";
  });
});
```

Comment: You're solution is adequate but what about this case http://jsfiddle.net/8KA8q/6/

Comment: trim just remove first and last white space. you can use regex for edvanced text manipulation. please try http://jsfiddle.net/8KA8q/9/

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is .prepend() instead of .append();

append places it as a last child, prepend as a first child.

also if that doesnt work play with .appendto() and .prependto().

Good luck

[Take a Look](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

Comment: there are no siblings of new textarea... `append` vs `prepend` is irrelevant, could just as easily use `html()` method and cut code down even more